# Editing wired connection

Tags: networking

I'm not sure what is happening here, but every time I typed into my clone MAC address the save box goes grey.

What can I do to change this?

Basically my wired network is not saving and I think this could be the reason why I'm not getting access to Ubuntu network server.

Second part of the question is I noticed my update is not from the secured server, what can i do to chabge this

Comment: it is not responding from any value, tried 00: dd: tried mixing still no response.

Comment: Are you suggesting i use your value instead mine? Nothing works, don't matter how or what i put there it does not work. It is completely greyed with no save box

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same trouble and found I had to go into 'Edit Connections'- just as you have done apparently and (this worked for my connection)- it should be the same;

Make sure the Connection Name is not "wired something" but it should be " Auto (eth0)
             MTU should be set to automatic

```
         IP v4 should be Automatic (DHCP),   And the boxes for "Require IP 4 addressingfor this connection to complete, AND Available to all users, should BOTH be ticked
           IP v6Settings should be  Method: Ignore,  And the ' Available to all users, should be Ticked for yes. 

                           I hope it works for you
```